# How to get specific model profile after authorization?

Tags: laravel

Here are some user profiles like: `DoctorModel, UserModel, ClinicModel.`

Each has own set of fields in database.

How to add concrete model in global scope when user is authorized to be able get model fields across all application.

For exmaple if user authorized as clinic I want to get from this model field `nameClinic` everywhere.

Now by defaul I got `UserModel` form `Auth::user()`

Comment: Any ideas, I think it is trivial issue

Answer (score 0):

IMO this is somewhat a wrong approach. You can maintain a UserModel for all types of Users and the details that might change can be held on other Models.
For example, the `ClinicModel belongsTo` relationship on `UserModel` and holds the details specific to the clinic over there.

Comment: So, you meant to set all relations betwen userModel and DoctorModel and ClinicModel to be able get data from user model? Is it good idea to load all models into user model after entry user? Could you explain more, how to do that? Because I use roles/permisison library. Maybe it already solves this issue